# Facebook event without longitude/latitude but still showing a map

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-events

I'm retrieving events and I'm using longitude/latitude to display them on a map.

Some events don't correspond to a Facebook place and only have an address typed by the creator of the event.

When I retrieve the event using Facebook graph explorer, I get a venue name.

However, when I look at the event, it has a map so Bing maps could tell me the longitude/latitude of the venue.

Do you know if it is possible to have access to those coordinates ?

Ex : https://www.facebook.com/events/225853517583316/

Graph explorer gives :

```
{
 "id": "225853517583316", 
 "owner": {
 "category": "Arts/entertainment/nightlife", 
 "category_list": [
  {
    "id": "133436743388217", 
    "name": "Arts & Entertainment"
  }
 ], 
 "name": "Dansez-Vous français ?", 
 "id": "212459588811011"
 }, 
 "name": "DANSEZ-VOUS SAINT NICOLAS ?", 
 "description": "Le vendredi 6 décembre, c’est Saint Nicolas !\n\nEt comme chaque année   désormais, Dansez-vous français? célébrera, chez Jour de fête, ce grand Saint qui apporte des cadeaux, des bonbons, des mecs et des nanas ! \n\nS’il n’est pas trop fatigué, Saint-Nicolas sera là, accompagné de son fidèle Père Fouettard qui ne manquera pas de vous corriger comme il se doit. \n\nMais quoi qu’il en soit, une chose est sûre: DJ Cheapy (et sa déferlante de tubes) accompagnera, cette année encore, Messieurs Pascualino et Röze aux platines. \n\nQue vous soyez un enfant sage ou une petite canaille n’aura plus aucune importance sur le dancefloor ! Vous pourrez danser toute la nuit et embrasser qui vous voulez (et même tirer sur la barbe de Saint Nicolas). \n\n\nDANSEZ-VOUS SAINT NICOLAS ? \nVendredi 6 décembre 2013\nDès 23h\nJOUR DE FÊTE\n181 Boulevard Anspach\n1000 Bruxelles\nMétro : Anneessens / Bourse \n \nIllustrations : Mademoiselle Annette\nTexte : François Sagan \n\nMerci à Rachel, Kusje et Darakan", 
 "start_time": "2013-12-06T23:00:00+0100", 
 "end_time": "2013-12-07T18:00:00+0100", 
 "timezone": "Europe/Brussels", 
 "is_date_only": false, 
 "location": "Jour De Fête 181 Boulevard Anspach 1000 Bruxelles", 
 "venue": {
   "name": "Jour De Fête 181 Boulevard Anspach 1000 Bruxelles"
 }, 
 "privacy": "OPEN", 
 "updated_time": "2013-11-20T19:14:22+0000"
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best you can do from the api is get the location of the Page associated with the event.
In your example, the page id is 212459588811011.

Then query the page object to get long/lat:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=212459588811011

Comment: It could indeed work. Alas, in this example, it doesn't work since the location of the event is not the location of the page. Thank you anyway.